# vaadin delete row on keyboard event

Tags: java, vaadin

How to handle keyboard event on the selected row in the table?
I mean, for example, I selected a row and I want to delete using keyboard button `delete`.

How to do it? What listener I should use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use ShortcutListener:

```
    table.setSelectable(true);
    table.addShortcutListener(new ShortcutListener("", KeyCode.DELETE, new int[10])
    {

        @Override
        public void handleAction(Object sender, Object target)
        {
            table.getValue(); //returns selected rows
            if (getKeyCode() == KeyCode.DELETE)
            {
                System.out.println("Merry Christmas");
            }
        }
    });
```